# Strange <div> offset

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<div>` blocks placed side by side. They are **identical** with the only difference being that the last `<div>` (on the far right) has a bit more text in it. However, all the blocks have a fixed width and height. For some reason, the last `<div>` is placed higher than the rest. I cannot figure this out for the life of me!

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrSF4/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should apply `vertical-align: top` to all the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrSF4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have to vertically align then, e.g. `vertical-align:top;`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZrSF4/2/